# How to change specific vscode theme parameters?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to change specific vscode theme parameters? In my case I want to change "wordHighlight" and "wordHighlightStrong". I try:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {

        }
    ]
},
```

But can't understand what to write.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "var.identifier",
        "foreground": "#00FF00",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
    }]
}
```

hint: press `F1` then enter `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` (this works in VSCode Version 1.17.0).
[also there is an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34065)

see:
[TextMate Grammars](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_textmate-grammars)
[Themes, Snippets and Colorizers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers)
[TextMate Scope Selectors](https://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors.html)
[TextMate Language Grammars](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars)

I hope this helps.